# Error In Connecting Mongodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
C:\Users\abc\Desktop\node>node connectiom.js
```

> module.js:327
>
> ```
> throw err;
> ^
> ```
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\node\connectiom.js'
>
> ```
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
> at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
> at startup (node.js:139:18)
> at node.js:974:3
> ```

code is:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/my_database_name';

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {

        console.log('Connection established to', url);


        db.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: check the file exists and the correct name

Comment: ya,my mistake...,but still error is                                                                      Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error: { [MongoError: connection 0 to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connection 0 to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out' }

Comment: You should now check to make sure you have mongodb up and running. For example, try running mongo in the command line and see if you can connect to your database. Either way, it sounds like your original question was a typo which is now solved. I would suggest editing your question or opening a new one.